# AngularJS modal async close doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am creating a modal and closing it once data comes in the background.

```
var modal = modal.open({..some params..});

//after data loads
modal.close();
```

So my problem is, since everything is asynchronous if my data comes instantaneously then my modal.close() executes before modal opens fully and then my screen remains stuck with the modal screen.

One solution I found is adding a timeout to the modal.close

```
$timeout(function() {
 modal.close();
}, 1)
```

This works but is it the right way to do it? Or there is some other better solution?

Comment: How are you getting the data? If using angular $http service, you can use the success/error on the returned promise object to broadcast a message and then your controllers can act on it....

Comment: I get the data from a cache service which already has data cached!

Comment: What is the purpose of this modal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modal instance has an `opened` promise on it that you should use to guarantee the modal has finished opening before you try to close it. From [the docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/):

> `opened` - a promise that is resolved when a modal gets opened after downloading content's template and resolving all variables
>
> `rendered` - a promise that is resolved when a modal is rendered.

Mixing it with your HTTP request might look like

```
modal = $modal.open({...})
$http.get(...).then(function(response) {
  modal.opened.then(modal.close)
})
```

Here's a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/GlteZiJM94ldNtLTKjLQ?p=info) of both the way you're currently doing it and doing it using `opened`.

```
$scope.open = ->
  modalInstance = $modal.open(
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
  )

  if $scope.work
    modalInstance.opened.then(->
      modalInstance.close()
    )
  else 
    modalInstance.close()
```